# High resolution app backgrounds?

Tags: android, performance, android-drawable

and i would like to have a nice high resolution background for it.
If i mind galaxy S4 and galaxy Note3, they have 1080 x 1920 px screens.

That means my 1080 x 1920 px background will be 3 MB. 
What!?? Yes. My whole app should be 3 MB not only one drawable piece.

So my question is, how developers solve this? I would like to have a nice textured well designed background, if it would be flat design, there wouldnt be problems like this.

And okay.. lets say Galaxy S4 and Note3 have really big amount of memory and fast processor and i use that 3MB background, but... what happens when somebody would like to use my app with a low budget device? Maybe its cannot even show that big image.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: You maths is wrong.  Unless you are already inscaling, your bitmap will need about 8MB (1080 x 1920 x 4 bytes).  There are many answers on here already about how to load bitmaps efficiently.

Comment: This is where a TILE and/or a GRADIENT (in any combination - i.e. a LayerList) can help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about other devices you should simply define different resources along with the correct size qualifiers, like stated in the Android [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

> `smallestWidth    sw<N>dp`
>
> **Examples:** sw600dp sw720dp
>
> The fundamental size of a screen, as
>   indicated by the shortest dimension of the available screen area.
>   Specifically, the device's smallestWidth is the shortest of the
>   screen's available height and width (you may also think of it as the
>   "smallest possible width" for the screen). You can use this qualifier
>   to ensure that, regardless of the screen's current orientation, your
>   application's has at least `<N>` dps of width available for it UI.
>
> ...

Basically you can define a `drawable-sw<N>dp` for each family of screens you want to support, putting in there targeted pictures as you need.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to change the resolution of your image. I created a 1024 x 768 PNG background image and its size was only around 300kb.

Check your image resolution. I recommend 72 pixels/inch. I'm not sure if there's any other softwares, but you can check and change your resolution on Adobe Photoshop if you go to Image -> Image Size. You might need to uncheck 'Resample Image' I think.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  The file size has nothing to do with how much memory is required since the bitmap is compressed when saved.  Your bitmap will require about 3MB when loaded. The resolution also has nothing to do with the bitmap.  I can load exactly the same bitmap in 2 different ImageViews on the same screen and they will have different pixels per inch.  PPI is only relevant when the image is rendered.

Comment: Oh ok I see... I think